# Using tick function in a-frame to update object position based on camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

I'm using A-Frame and want an object to move along with the camera. To do this, I put together a component that updates the object's position based on the camera position:

```
      AFRAME.registerComponent('follow', {
    schema: {
      distance: {type: 'vec3'},
      target: {type: 'selector'}
    },

    tick: function() {
      const targetItem = this.data.target;
      const relativePosition = this.data.distance

      var tempPos = targetItem.getAttribute("position").split(" ").map(Number);

      targetPos = new THREE.Vector3(relativePosition.x + tempPos[0], relativePosition.y + tempPos[1], relativePosition.z + tempPos[2]);

      this.el.setAttribute('position', targetPos)
    }
  });
```

This works fine when I use `init` instead of `tick` but since it's an init function it only updates it once at the start of the scene. For some reason, when I use `tick` everything breaks. Am I using it wrong? Should I do something different to continually update it's position?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I should mention the goal is to have something follow around, but *not* be fixed to your view. Think Navi from Ocarina of Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received a solution from outside SO:

I needed to put my WASD controller on the entity containing the camera:

```
<a-entity id="character" position="0 2 3"  wasd-controls look-controls>
  <a-entity id="camera" camera>
    <a-ring radius-outer="0.03" radius-inner="0.02"
            position="0 0 -1"
            material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
            cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500">
    </a-ring>
    </a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Then, I needed to change the function:

```
 tick() {
          const targetItem = this.data.target;
          var distance = this.data.distance;
          var targetPosition = targetItem.getAttribute('position');
          this.el.setAttribute('position',{
            x: targetPosition.x + distance.x,
            y: targetPosition.y + distance.y,
            z: targetPosition.z + distance.z
          });
```

And then it worked!